# PDB - Set or change Variable in interactive mode

Tags: python, pdb

Currently, when I modify variables inside the interactive interpreter in pdb, it doesn't carry over outside the interactive session. Is there a way to do this?(I'm already aware of exec, !). However, I want to perform some multi-line operations.

```
(Pdb) c
(Pdb) pp locals()['a']
*** KeyError: 'a'
(Pdb) !a=2
(Pdb) pp locals()['a']
2
(Pdb) !del a             
(Pdb) pp locals()['a']   
*** KeyError: 'a'        
(Pdb) interact                       
*interactive*                        
>>> a=2                              
>>>                                  
now exiting InteractiveConsole...    
(Pdb) pp locals()['a']               
*** KeyError: 'a'
```

Comment: As far as I understand, when you enter the interactive mode you are not in the same scope, but you work with a copy of the scope. So when you change a variable in interactive mode, you only change the copy and not the original. And when you exit the interactive mode, you return to the unchanged original scope. What kind of multi-line operations do you want to execute? Can they be written in one line or separated by semicolons?

Comment: try except operations for example

Comment: Looking at the [`pdb.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/pdb.py#L1384) source code, the statements `ns = {**self.curframe.f_globals, **self.curframe_locals}; code.interact("*interactive*", local=ns)` get executed when the `interact` command is invoked. My guess is that `ns` is an abbreviation for `namespace`; the `interact` command creates a separate namespace (initialized with variables from the current pdb frame), and changes to that namespace are not reflected in pdb once the interactive prompt is exited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code to execute multi line code while debugging in `pdb/ipdb`

```
!import code; code.interact(local=vars())
```

This will enter into `interactive console`

The `pdb` is only meant for checking your code and any changes there will apply for that execution only and will not alter your code

Comment: Marking this one as correct over @Jasha's answer primarily because this can be done at anytime without any prior setup.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Nbfour and myself in the comments above, the default `pdb.Pdb` class does not operate on the same namespace as that used by the current frame being debugged. Instead, the dict containing local variables is copied, and the interactive-mode works on that copied dict. This occurs in the `do_interact` method defined by the default `Pdb` class.

Subclassing `pdb.Pdb`, we can achieve the desired behavior:

```
import pdb
import code

class MyPdb(pdb.Pdb):
    def do_interact(self, arg):
        code.interact("*interactive*", local=self.curframe_locals)

MyPdb().set_trace()
```

Running the above script, our interactive-mode changes to local state are now permanent:

```
(Pdb) pp locals()['a']
*** KeyError: 'a'
(Pdb) !a=2
(Pdb) pp locals()['a']
2
(Pdb) !del a
(Pdb) pp locals()['a']
*** KeyError: 'a'
(Pdb) interact
*interactive*
>>> a=2
>>>
now exiting InteractiveConsole...
(Pdb) pp locals()['a']
2
```